# How to reference cell to the left (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to do some calculations based on team results in Excel. The format is:

```
Team | Player | Yards
 A   |   x    |  100
 B   |   y    |  142
 A   |   z    |   93
```

I'd like to be able to sum all the yards for a particular team, so for example if there are several players from team A then it sums their yardage. How would I go about doing this?

The dataset is long enough that it is impractical to do it all manually.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

For example, if your team is in the A column, the players are in the B column and the Yards are in the C column, you can use the formula like this:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "A", C:C)
```

which sums the yards of the team A.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SUMIF formula. See below:

[image]

A SUMIF formula will add the values if a certain condition is true which is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: While the animation looks cool and flashy, it really serves no purpose here and actually makes your answer harder to follow than a typed formula.

Comment: @Excellll That's your opinion however this shows how the formula changes. Since this is a rather basic question that was asked, I figured he could see the formula differences on each line. Thank you for your opinion though

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy with a [Pivot](https://support.office.com/en-AU/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) Table (Insert > Pivot Table). Select `Team` as *Row lables* and choos the *Sum of `Yards`* as *Values*:

[image: pivot table]